# Incorrect syntax near 'IF'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the following SP (minified for clarity):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp
    @id int,
    @filter varchar(255) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    IF (NULLIF(@id, 0) IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        WITH cte AS
        (
            --SELECT here...
        )

        IF (NULLIF(@filter, '') IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM cte;
        END
    END
END
```

I get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'IF'

The 'IF' being on the line:

> IF (NULLIF(@filter, '') IS NULL)

Why do I get this error and what's the correct way to formulate the above SQL syntax?

Comment: A CTE must be used by the statement that immediately follows its definition. You can't insert some *arbitrary control flow* statements into the middle like that.

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas The problem is not the `NULLIF` clause but the 'IF' because it's after the `WITH cte (..)`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for the explanation. Would I incur performance issues if I insert the cte into a table variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Inner If statement is in wrong place. The with format is

```
With <col> as 
(
  ---
)
SELECT ---
```

futhermore I don't think that NULLIF has purpose in here. In general, if you can write without using function, do not use function (because of the performance considerations)

Final procedure would be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp
    @id int,
    @filter varchar(255) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@id != 0)
    BEGIN
        IF (@filter = '')
        BEGIN
            WITH cte AS
            (
                --SELECT here...
            )
            SELECT *
            FROM cte;
        END
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The CTE needs to be inside the "IF (NULLIF(@filter, '') IS NULL)". The CTE has to be used immediately after being created. This should work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp
    @id int,
    @filter varchar(255) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    IF (NULLIF(@id, 0) IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        IF (NULLIF(@filter, '') IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            WITH cte AS
            (
                --SELECT here...
            )
            SELECT *
            FROM cte;
        END
    END
END
```